# Python Debug not working on SSH FS (remote host)

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger, sshfs

#### Issue:

I am using VSCode version 1.69.1 on Mac (Version details at the bottom). From Mac, I connect to a remote repo using [SSH FS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs)

When I click on 'run' > 'Start Debugging' or 'Run Without Debugging' on a remote python file, the "Run and Debug pane opens" but the file is not run [![Pane is blank][1]][1]

The debugger works for local repos (hosted on Mac).

I have tried reinstalling the Python extension, removed the ~/.vscode-server on the remote server, re-install VSCode on the Mac but nothing seem to have helped.

This was earlier working (tried a week back) but unsure what changed.
From the terminal (connected to remote host, rendered by SSH FS, I am able to run
`python test.py` and that works

Launch.json file for python

```
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Version details

```
Commit: b06ae3b2d2dbfe28bca3134cc6be65935cdfea6a
Date: 2022-07-12T08:21:51.333Z (1 day ago)
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.5.0
```

````
Id: Kelvin.vscode-sshfs
Description: File system, terminal and task provider using SSH
Version: 1.25.0
Publisher: Kelvin Schoofs
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/elruD.png
````

Comment: do you get an error? if so, can you add an image of the error?

Comment: Thanks @Aking for taking a look.
 No, there was no error. 
For local files when I click run I see following in the terminal:
```cd /Users/dev/src/nilebot ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/dev/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 56060 -- /Users/dev/test.py ```

For remote files, I do not see anything on the terminal.  Looks like something that triggers the command is broken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python Debugger version v2022.10.0 seems to be broken for SSH-FS.
Using the previous version of Python extension addressed it.

To install an older version of an extension, click on gear icon> select "Install another version"  and select version to install.

[image: Install Another Version]

I used version v2022.8.1, and that works

Comment: In addition: It's important to do this in the ssh-rider under extensions. Accidentally I reverted the locally installed version without any effects.

Comment: This solved my issue, two subtle things though: restart your IDE after downgrading, and if you didn't use your IDE for a while it may happen that VS code automatically upgrades it to a higher version again (I don't know why, how or when , but for me it was the case, so check the version again if it stops working again).